# Fastest way to store these phrases

Tags: php, algorithm, search

Building a simple algorithm where, based on various inputs (x, y, z), a phrase will be sent back to the user. What's the fastest way to store and search for these phrases?

Currently, I'm using various if statements. But I'm wondering if I should instead use some sort of dictionary, or hash maps.

I've posted a code sample here.

Thank you!

```
  for ( $i=0 ; $i < count($age) ; $i++ ) {
    if ($age[$i] >= 95) { 
      $something = "You need a plant";
    } elseif ($age[$i] >= 85 && $age[$i] < 95) {
      $something = "You need a small rug and a plant";
    } elseif ($age[$i] >= 75 && $age[$i] < 85) {
      $something = "You need a rug";
    } elseif ($age[$i] >= 60 && $age[$i] < 75) {
      $something = "You need a coffee table";
    } elseif ($age[$i] >= 55 && $age[$i] < 60) {
      $something = "You need a small table";
    } elseif ($age[$i] >= 51 && $age[$i] < 55) {
      $something = "You need a table";
    } elseif ($age[$i] >= 42 && $age[$i] < 51) {
      $something = "You need a knife";
    } elseif ($age[$i] >= 35 && $age[$i] < 42) {
      $something = "You need a knife and a jar";
    } elseif ($age[$i] >= 22 && $age[$i] < 35) {
      $something = "You need a knife, bowl, jar and a small book";
    } elseif ($age[$i] >= 5 && $age[$i] < 22) {
      $something = "You need a knife, bowl, jar and a book";
    } else {
      $something = "Go back to sleep";
    }

    if ($somethingElse[$i] >= 30) {
      $also = " and we'll see you tomorrow!";
    } else {
      $also = ".";
    }

    $phrase[$i] = ''.$something.''.$also.'';
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried with, sample input and expected  output for it, and tag the question with the programming language you are using.

Comment: Updated with code sample.

Comment: Depends really on the kind of tests you have to do. Probably best you give a concrete case, for which we can give a concrete answer. The answer depends much on how much of those conditions can be treated in a similar way. If you have `$x > 3`, then `$x > 2`, `$x > 0`, etc... then there is room for improvement.

Comment: Thanks @trincot. I've updated my code sample. Yes, it's pretty unwieldy which is why I want to find a smarter way to do that. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the phrase, you could use an array with the age limits as keys and the texts as values. For the second part, which is more of a yes/no choice, you can use a ternary operator.

`foreach` is also nicer for looping over the *$age* array:

```
$phrases = [
    95 => "You need a plant",
    85 => "You need a small rug and a plant",
    75 => "You need a rug",
    65 => "You need a coffee table",
    55 => "You need a small table",
    51 => "You need a table",
    42 => "You need a knife",
    35 => "You need a knife and a jar",
    22 => "You need a knife, bowl, jar and a small book",
    5  => "You need a knife, bowl, jar and a book",
];

foreach ($age as $i => $a) {
    foreach ($phrases as $limit => $something) {
        if ($a >= $limit) break;
    }
    $also = $somethingElse[$i] >= 30 ? " and we'll see you tomorrow!" : ".";
    $phrase[] = "$something$also";
}
```

Note that unless you already had an array `$phrase`, you don't need to specify the index  *$i*, as `[]` will just make it append at the end. So in the end you only need *$i* for `$somethingElse`. The reason why it is still needed in the `foreach` syntax.

Comment: Awesome. Much cleaner. Thank you @trincot!

Comment: Please take note of a small correction: you missed the fact that you still need *$i* for `$somethingElse[$i]`. Corrected now (cf. `foreach`).